# How to enable/disable laptop's CD drive if I don't have administrative privileges

Tags: windows, optical-drive, privileges, compact-disc

I'm working in a network company. I don't have administrative privileges on my computer and every time I want to listen to my favorite CD, I need to contact the administrator, then going to his office and run the CD from his computer since on mine, CD drivers are disabled.

How can I avoid annoying him and enable/disable the CD drive anytime I like?

I'd need a simple solution using text through a shortcut, something like the

`%windir%\System32\rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation`

Comment: I don't think it's possible, but this might be one of those situations where challenging policy is a good idea. Why don't you ask your admin why you can't play music CDs. I would assume they want to stop you from running files off of data CDs or installing software via the CD-drive. But there are better group-policies to stop that then to disable hardware. Do you have access to USB drives if they are connected? You could always put the music files on a thumbdrive and play it through that device. If you don't have access to USB devices, maybe again, you need to ask why.

Comment: Why not stop using the company equipment for personal use and buy your own CD/MP3 player?

Comment: Additionally, if you do find the solution you're looking for, you very well may be terminated for breaking IT security policy. Just something to think about..

Comment: Try a usb cd/dvd drive

Answer (score 1):

If you can boot from the CD, use a live CD to run Linux when you want to play music.

Comment: won't that stop OP from doing work while listening to a CD? Why not just suggest a CD player?

Comment: I agree - bring a CD player is the better answer.  But it depends what work is.  The computer will still be useful - the liveCD could have a suite of productivity tools on it.